# Working example with SELECT datasource~* syntax

Tags: abap

I'm still baffled that examples given in the SAP keyword documentation are not accepted in a system of the respective ABAP version.

I'm trying to run the [example](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abapselect_clause_cols.htm#!ABAP_VARIANT_1@1@) given for `SELECT datasource~* ...` on an ABAP 7.40 system but get the error

> "," is not allowed here since it contains an invalid character or it is a keyword [...]

When removing the `,`, the error is

> No component exists with the name "*". "*".

The example in the [keyword documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abapselect_clause_cols.htm#!ABAP_VARIANT_1@1@) is

```
TYPES BEGIN OF structure.
TYPES carrname TYPE scarr-carrname.
INCLUDE TYPE spfli AS spfli.
TYPES url TYPE scarr-url.
TYPES END OF structure.

DATA itab TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF structure WITH EMPTY KEY.

SELECT scarr~carrname, spfli~*, scarr~url
       FROM scarr INNER JOIN spfli ON scarr~carrid = spfli~carrid
       INTO TABLE @itab.

cl_demo_output=>display( itab ).
```

What would be a correct example? And/or: which ABAP version should my system have to accept this example (and how to check that)?

Comment: That code works for me w/o issues. Which SAP_BASIS version and patch level/SP level are you using?

Comment: EHP7 for SAP ERP 6.0. Is that what you've asked for?

Comment: No. System > Status, Details button, line with component SAP_BASIS is the info you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword documentation you already referred to states that

> When data_source~* is used, the syntax check is performed in a [strict
>   mode](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenopensql_strict_mode_740_sp08.htm), which handles the statement more strictly than the regular
>   syntax check.

The documentation page on the strict mode is titled

> Strict Mode in Release 7.40, SP08

so I would assume that you need at least SAP_BASIS 740 SP08.

Answer (score 1):

I just copied that sample code and it works like a charm on my 7.40 SP11 system. You should check what SP level your Netweaver has. It can be done in the following way:

1. Go to System -> Status from the main menu
2. Press on the *Component* button in *SAP System data* to see component versions of your system.

You should see something like this:

[image]

`SAP_ABA` component is your ABAP server, and `SP-Level` column represents patch level of your AS.

Necessary patch level can bee seen in [ABAP Release-Specific changes](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abennews.htm) section of documentation, and here we can observe that this syntax is available [since 7.40, SP08](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abennews-740_sp08-open_sql.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_1@1@).
There is no searchable index of release-specific changes so you should search it manually.